# Trigger to detect changes in column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that gets called after changing the content of a record in column **X** in table **Y** and displays how many there are records in table **Y** with previous content in column **X**.

For example,

1. Change records field "color" from "blue" to "green",
2. Display how many records with field "color" set to "blue" there currently are.

Here's what I had already tried:

```
USE [DTBS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[dbo.how_many]
   ON [dbo].[Person]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (color)
        BEGIN

        DECLARE @color VARCHAR(32);
        DECLARE @count INT;

        SELECT @color = color FROM deleted;

        SELECT @count = COUNT(id)
        FROM Person
        WHERE Person.color = @color

        PRINT (@count)
    END
END
```

I am working on SQL Server Management Studio 2019 and currently nothing happens when I try to invoke the trigger.

Comment: You need to read [Inserted & Deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) because you are failing to take into account that they can have 0-N rows. Also while print might help you debug you don't want to leave that there for production - there is no mechanism for returning values from triggers.

Comment: And therefore you also need to handle the fact that multiple colours might change in the same update. You've also defined it as an insert trigger (in addition to update), insert triggers don't have a previous value.

Comment: `IF UPDATE` does not do what you think. If you want to know something has **actually** changed, you need to compare.

Comment: FYI SSMS is purely a client interface. Its not the database engine.

Comment: [Brent Ozar: The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to read about the [Inserted & Deleted Pseudo Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) as they can have 0-N rows and your trigger needs to handle that. Using a set-based approach solves this issue.
2. This leads to the fact that you could have multiple colours updated at the same time which you need to handle.
3. You don't want an `INSERT` trigger if you are detecting changes and want to access the old value.
4. Triggers are not designed to return data. I have shown you how to capture the information you want, but in the end you need a different mechanism to make use of it e.g. inserting into a different table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[dbo.how_many]
    ON [dbo].[Person]
    FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
    IF UPDATE (color) BEGIN

        -- This gives *all* the old colours prior to update
        SELECT D.Color
        FROM Inserted I
        INNER JOIN Deleted D ON D.id = I.id -- One assumes you have an id column
        -- Assuming Color is never null
        WHERE D.Color != I.Color
        GROUP BY D.Color;

        -- If you then want a count you would do
        SELECT COUNT(id), Color
        FROM Person
        WHERE Person.Color IN (
            -- Repeat query from above
            SELECT D.Color
            FROM Inserted I
            INNER JOIN Deleted D ON D.id = I.id
            WHERE D.Color != I.Color
            GROUP BY D.Color
        )
        GROUP BY Color;

    END;
END;
```